# Warbler not including gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, prawn, warbler

I'm having a problem where Warbler is not packaging up a few gems.  The gems are:

'prawn 0.11.1' - https://github.com/sandal/prawn
'prawnto 0.0.4' - https://github.com/jlsync/prawnto
'ttfunk 1.0.1'

I'm running Rails 3.0.5, JRuby 1.6.0 and Warbler 1.2.1.  I've tried to tell Warbler to include these gems in the warble.rb config file but that hasn't worked either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put these specs in the Gemfile, that should work.

e.g.:

```
source <repo-url>
git 'https://github.com/sandal/prawn' do
gem 'prawn'
end
...
```